# How to use sunAngle function in oce package

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the sun angle for known lat, lon, and times, and pass the sun angle result to a new column in the input file named df, but I keep getting the error message "lengths of longitude and useRefraction must match".  My script is:

df$sunangle <- sunAngle(df$ISO_DateTime_UTC, df$longitude, df$latitude, useRefraction = TRUE)

The input file, df, is

```
"sample" 1, 2, 3
"ISO_DateTime_UTC" 2018-04-17T13:15Z, 2018-04-17T13:15Z, 2018-04-17T15:30Z
"latitude" 40.466167, 40.398667, 40.335167
"longitude" -70.83, -70.828833, -70.8295
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've supplied 3 lat/long/time values and one `useRefraction` value - that's what the error message is telling you. Your next step should be to try it with 3 `useRefraction` values:

```
> sunAngle(df$ISO_DateTime_UTC,
    df$longitude,
    df$latitude,
    useRefraction = rep(TRUE,nrow(df)))
```

But that gives a new error:

```
Error in sunAngle(df$ISO_DateTime_UTC, df$longitude, df$latitude, useRefraction = rep(TRUE,  : 
  lengths of longitude, latitude and useRefraction must be 1 or the length of time
```

Which seems very odd because all the arguments are "the length of time".

The error is generated by this bit of code:

```
    if (nlongitude == 1) {
        longitude <- rep(longitude, length.out = nt)
        latitude <- rep(latitude, length.out = nt)
        useRefraction <- rep(useRefraction, length.out = nt)
    }
    else {
        stop("lengths of longitude, latitude and useRefraction must be 1 or the length of time")
    }
```

Which doesn't relate to the length of time at all. It errors like that if the number of longitude values isn't 1.

Changing that last test to something that passes in this instance:

```
    else if(nlongitude != nt){
        stop("lengths of longitude, latitude and useRefraction must be 1 or the length of time")
    }
```

gets us something that runs:

```
fixOut = as.data.frame(sunAngleFix(df$ISO_DateTime_UTC, df$longitude, df$latitude, rep(TRUE,3)))
                 time   azimuth altitude  diameter distance declination
1 2018-04-17 12:15:00  96.93771 24.33358 0.5311621 1.003837    10.56330
2 2018-04-17 12:15:00  96.90825 24.34258 0.5311621 1.003837    10.56330
3 2018-04-17 14:30:00 126.05918 48.24525 0.5311483 1.003863    10.59621
  rightAscension
1       25.48068
2       25.48068
3       25.56773
```

and gets identical results to running each row of the data frame separately:

```
origOut = do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, function(i)as.data.frame(sunAngleFix(df$ISO_DateTime_UTC[i], df$longitude[i], df$latitude[i], TRUE))))
```

```
> identical(fixOut, origOut)
[1] TRUE
```

This might be enough to convince me its doing the right thing when supplied with arguments that it would normally reject, but its probably worth reporting to the author at https://github.com/dankelley/oce/issues and referencing this question. At the very least the error message seems dishonest (the second one, your original is honest).

I think the easiest way to fix this is to use the `Vectorize` function to make a modified `sunAngle` function that works on each element of your data in turn:

Sample data;

```
d <- data.frame(
    t = c("2018-04-17 13:15Z", "2018-04-17 13:15Z", "2018-04-17 15:30Z") |> as.POSIXct(),
    lat = c(40.466167, 40.398667, 40.335167),
    lon = c(-70.83, -70.828833, -70.8295),
    ref = rep(TRUE, 3)
)
```

make version that magically evaluates each i-th element of the arguments in turn:

```
vsunAngle = Vectorize(sunAngle, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

And it runs and returns this:

```
vout = vsunAngle(d$t, d$lat, d$lon, d$ref)
```

which is a list of the results for each single element of the arguments, which you can bind up into a data frame:

```
> do.call(rbind,vout)
     time                azimuth  altitude  diameter  distance declination
[1,] 2018-04-17 12:15:00 316.5287 3.533653  0.5311621 1.003837 10.5633    
[2,] 2018-04-17 12:15:00 316.5933 3.54901   0.5311621 1.003837 10.5633    
[3,] 2018-04-17 14:30:00 284.8165 -6.099628 0.5311483 1.003863 10.59621   
     rightAscension
[1,] 25.48068      
[2,] 25.48068      
[3,] 25.56773
```

Note there's a one-hour change in the date-times which I suspect is daylight saving time-related in my locale - yes my date-times are input as BST (British Summer Time).

Comment: Now issue 2178 https://github.com/dankelley/oce/issues/2178

Comment: So, how exactly do you recommend fixing my original bit of code? I'm not sure what you are recommending as a solution.  Talk to me like I'm an R-beginner (which I am!).

Comment: Edited to add the use of `Vectorize` to create a new function that works like the original but handles vector arguments cleanly. Try that....